# JReble for Android error

Tags: android, jrebel

I use JRebel for Android plugin for Android Studio to compile my project. When I run it on device it shows me "Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`.

I use java 1.8 and I have enabled Jack. So why does it happen? I didn't try remove `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`，because I used a lot of Java 8 language features.

Comment: I think it is nothing with JRebel, what if you jst remove jrebel plugin (for test), does it fix build?

Comment: Yes,I use JRebel to raise my build speed。I changed to jdk 1.7 and it worked

Comment: Also not the perfect solution

Comment: Maybe later they will add jdk1.8 support